# Water runs from portafilter when backflush

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine

I want to backflush my espresso machine but water still comes out just like I am using a normal filter and not the blind one. What can be the problem?

Comment: You are backflushing with a regular filter, not with a blind filter? That's not backflushing, that's just pushing water through the portafilter.

Comment: @technical_difficulty please re-read my post. Also someone has already answered to me but thanks!

Comment: If that's the case, then the water wouldn't run through the portafilter, right? I think your question needs more clarity to be answered in a way that can be helpful to other users. Where is the water coming through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the gasket around the group head is damaged or worn out. Damage can occur if you overtighten the portafilter when locking it in place to brew, and wear occurs just by using the machine normally. Under normal use (once daily at least five days a week), a group head gasket will need to be replaced about every six months.